# Multiple importation of Access database

Tags: excel, vba, database, import

I am struggling in creating a macro developed for import different database Access, each on a separate Excel sheet. Everything is running until I reach the position where I pasted a registered macro and herein I replaced the path with the created variable `percorso` containing the path of the different files.

I would like to ask if somebody can indicate me the correct syntax to avoid the error: `Runtime error 1004`

Below I report the whole code, after removing all the worksheets different from "Home" I start adding the content from access.

```
Sub Importazione()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim file As Object
    Dim percorso As String
    Dim nome As String
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim ultimo1 As Integer
    Dim ultimo2 As Integer
    Dim maxValue As Long
    Dim xWs As Worksheet    
    
    n = 2
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If xWs.Name <> "Home" Then
            xWs.Delete
        End If
    Next
             
        
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.Filesystemobject")
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path)
    For Each file In folder.Files
        If UCase(file.Name) Like "*.MDB" Then
            Debug.Print file.Path, file.Name
            
            nome = Replace(file.Name, ".mdb", "")         
            nome = Replace(nome, "-", "_")         
            percorso = file.Path
         
            Sheets.Add.Name = "Foglio" & n
            Sheets("Foglio" & n).Select
    
            ''' IMPORTATION CODE REGISTRED USING REGISTER MACRO
            ''' I CHANGE THE PATH WITH THE CREATED VARIABLE "percorso" I THINK HERE IS THE SYNTAX MISTAKE
    
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
            With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
                "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source= & percorso & ;Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Datab" _
                , _
                "ase Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global B" _
                , _
                "ulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Je" _
                , _
                "t OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support " _
                , _
                "Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Va" _
                , "lidation=False"), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
                .CommandType = xlCmdTable
                .CommandText = Array("Test")
                .RowNumbers = False
                .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                .PreserveFormatting = True
                .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                .BackgroundQuery = True
                .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
                .SavePassword = False
                .SaveData = True
                .AdjustColumnWidth = True
                .RefreshPeriod = 0
                .PreserveColumnInfo = True
                .SourceDataFile = """ & percorso & """
                .ListObject.DisplayName = "Tabella__29163"
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            End With
        End If
    Next 
End Sub
```

I am mostly sure the problem is that `Source= & percorso &` but I do not know how to input it correctly.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Does this link help?

http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_MainPage.htm

Comment: I checked but I didn't find what I am looking for. I am only trying to import a set of Access database and open each on a separate excel sheet. I know it is quite unusual and difficult ...